# Why is the file descriptor opened and read only once?

Tags: bash, file-descriptors, stdin

Why can it be used only 1 time when we open the file descriptor ourselves and redirect it to stdin?
Please take a look at the example below to understand what I want to say. After reading it once with the cat command, the file is not read via the same file descriptor for the second time.

```
└─$ exec 6< input.txt
└─$ cat <&6
i am just string
and another string..
└─$ cat <&6
└─$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To print the file, the first `cat` has to read it until the end.
`exec 6< input.txt` causes the shell to hold the file descriptor until the
shell dies or closes it, so the file offset still points to the end of the
file when the second `cat` is invoked, which thus writes nothing to stdout.

If on a Linux-based system, you can see that happening by peeking into the file descriptor info:

```
echo "File contents" > input.txt
exec 6< input.txt
cat "/proc/$$/fdinfo/6"
cat <&6
cat "/proc/$$/fdinfo/6"
cat <&6
```

If you execute that script, you will get something like

```
pos:    0
flags:  0100000
mnt_id: 113
File contents
pos:    14
flags:  0100000
mnt_id: 113
```

confirming that the offset (`pos`) is not 0
when the second `cat` is executed, but instead points to its end.

To reset the offset, you can add another `exec 6< input.txt` in between the `cat`s.

Comment: ksh93 and zsh can *rewind* ksh93 has a `exec <#((0))` to rewind. And `zsh` has `sysseek 0` (in the `zsh/system` module), and you can always execute another command to do the `lseek()`.

Comment: Yes, you can do `exec 3<#((0))` or `3>#((0))` like with other redirection operators.